# Broken Merge Sort

Tags: sorting, struct, segmentation-fault, mergesort

Good morning, Stack Overflow. You guys helped me out on an earlier assignment, and I'm hoping to get a little help on this one.

It's a programming assignment relating to sorts, one part of which is to write a working implementation of merge sort.

I adapted my solution from the pseudocode the professor used in class, but I'm getting an annoying segfault at the indicated location.

This method is sorting an array of structs, with data_t defined as struct pointers.

The struct definition:

```
typedef struct {
int id;
int salary;
} employee_t;

typedef employee_t* data_t;
```

They're being sorted by salary, which is a randomly generated number from 40,000 to 90,000.

Here's the actual method

```
void merge_sort(data_t items[], size_t n)
{
if (n < 2)
  return;

size_t mid = (n / 2);

data_t *left = malloc(sizeof(data_t) * mid);
data_t *right = malloc(sizeof(data_t) * (n - mid));

for (int y = 0; y < mid; y++)
{
  left[y] = items[y];
}

for (int z = mid; z < n; z++)
{
  right[z] = items[z];
}

merge_sort(left, mid);
merge_sort(right, (n - mid));

size_t l, r, i;
l = 0;
r = 0;

for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
{
  if ((l < mid) && ((r >= (n - mid)) || ((left[l]->salary) <=  (right[r]->salary))))
  {
     items[i] = left[l++];
  }
  else
  { 
     items[i] = right[r++];
  }
}

free(left);
free(right);  
}
```

Note that I haven't made it as far as the end, so the array frees might be incorrectly located.

The segfault always occurs when I try to access right[r]->salary, so I'm assuming this is related to a null pointer, or similar. However, I'm extremely new to sorting, and I don't know exactly where to properly implement a check.

Any advice is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance there's this fix:

```
    for (int z = mid; z < n; z++)
    {
        right[z-mid] = items[z];
    }
```

Comment: ...wow. That actually worked. Can somebody explain why? It's 4 AM, and my brain isn't working terribly well.

Comment: The indexes for right[] go from 0 to n-mid-1. Since z starts at mid, you need to subtract mid from z before using it as an index to right[].

Comment: Thanks. This'll make more sense after I get some sleep.